# My browser's default font seems to have become Arial Black. How can I fix it?

Tags: windows, browser, fonts

I'm facing a strange issue whereby ALL the browsers on my home computer (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, Opera) are defaulting to Arial Black. The font settings are normal - Times New Roman, Arial, Courier etc. - but that doesn't seem to be making a difference.

This is how the web should look:

[image: This is how the web should look]

And this is how it looks on my computer:

[image: This is how it looks on my computer]

I thought it might be a rogue extension, but then how would this affect both Chrome and Firefox. I have NO add-ons installed in Firefox. And what about Safari and IE?

I have a similar problem with my work computer, but the font there isn't Arial Black. I don't know what font it is, but it's not the regular Arial.

Where can I start looking?

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on an mid-2011 iMac. This problem does not occur when I am in Mac OS X on the same computer.

Comment: Something's borked in your Windows Fonts folder. Messed-up permissions?

Comment: I checked that the first. Nothing seems wrong. All fonts are present and are opening fine. I even downloaded some default fonts pack (shared on some Windows 7 forum) and replaced existing fonts, but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently had this problem. It was because I had recently installed Helvetica Neue font and it was messing with FireFox. Hopefully if you have that and uninstall it, it will fix the problem for you like it did me.

Comment: No problems man. Ironically, back then "HelveticaNeueLT Std Blk Ext" didn't seem to work properly. Adobe Fireworks/Photoshop didn't recognize it had been installed in Windows. Now, in Windows 8.1 and 10, it is recognized by Adobe products, and hasn't messed-up my firefox font either. No idea why it didn't work back then but does work for me currently, but I'm glad it fixed your problem too :)

Answer (score 1):

If somehow you lost the Arial font, Windows will default for the next closest option. Search for Arial, you might only find Arial Black being installed in your computer. Reinstall Arial and problem solved.

Comment: Confirmed. Client had somehow corrupted (or installed accidentally over) the default Arial font. Grabbing the font from another computer and reinstalling the Arial font fixed the problem for us. When we viewed the font in the font explorer, all fonts but "Arial Black" showed up as shortcuts. Reinstallation fixed them to not be shortcuts and everything worked almost immediately without the need to reboot.